# How to reduce Google Gemini AI response to less than 1000 characters without truncated its response

Tags: python-3.x, google-gemini

> Example prompt: *Make a story about turtle and pig.*
> This could create more than 1000 character story.
> I tried reducing `max_output_tokens` with different values.
> I tried adding text in the prompt like *Make a story about turtle and pig. Make it less than 1000 characters* or *...make it short story* which can't be use for general purpose.
> Using substring might not good option.

In OpenAI you can add *instruction* to do this without any problem to the story.

Output a story with less than 1000 characters., or how can I use *instruction *like OpenAI the same method to do in Gemini model

**UPDATE:**
I already **solved** the problem, I just added the prompt like *"... Answer should be less than 200 words"*

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are 3-4 characters each, so 1000 tokens would output 3-4 thousand characters. Try setting the token limit to something like 250.
For example:

```
client.max_output_tokens = 250
answer = client.generate_content(query, safety_settings = safe)
```

Where `client` is your genai model.